# Text-in-Text on specific character

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

A few years back a member of our group committed suicide. Before he passed he wrote a song with 5 verses, and there are 5 of us remaining. What I am attempting to do here is replace the semi-colon with a verse in the shape of the semi-colon. This is a design concept for a tattoo artist, as we're all going to get the same tattoo, each with a different verse. When we are together, his song will be complete.

I've figured out how to shape the smaller text into the larger text, but I am not getting the option to create a mask for the semi-colon. I am not very familiar with Illustrator, so I am sure I am missing some obvious but fundamental step.

What I did to get to this point:

- Created a text outline
- Ungrouped the larger text
- Copied the semi-colon onto its own layer
- Deleted the semi-color from the Background text layer

I've been fiddling with this for a while now, so I may have clicked something I shouldn't have.

[image]

Comment: I'm no tattoo expert, but If you want the verses to be readable, that's going to be a big tattoo. Especially when the shape of the semicolon is what it is, you can perhaps fit a max of 2 words side by side. I can't help but feel you have to put the verses somewhere outside of the semicolon unless you want like a full back tattoo.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the text to outlines, then do *Object > Compound Path > Release*. Then select the shape. Then, with the text tool selected, click just inside the path, and you should be able to type inside the shapes.

[image]